# How to find cube root of value using Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have tried the following:

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> tf.enable_eager_execution()
>>> tf.math.pow(3,3)
2019-05-06 16:05:51.508296: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
<tf.Tensor: id=3, shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=27>
>>> tf.math.pow(9,(1/3))
<tf.Tensor: id=7, shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=1>
>>> tf.math.pow(27,(1/3))
<tf.Tensor: id=11, shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=1>
>>> tf.math.pow(27,0.3)
<tf.Tensor: id=15, shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=1>
>>> tf.math.pow(4,0.5)
<tf.Tensor: id=19, shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=1>
>>> tf.math.pow(4,1/2)
<tf.Tensor: id=23, shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=1>
```

I know that `sqrt` is used for square root. But if I need the cube root of a number, how I can calculate it with tensorflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this please:

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> tf.enable_eager_execution()
>>> tf.math.pow(27.0,1.0/3.0)
2019-05-06 16:22:39.403646: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
<tf.Tensor: id=3, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=3.0>
```

Guess the  issue is with datatype.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean seeing the result, you can use `InteractiveSession` and `eval`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.InteractiveSession()
tf.pow(27.0,1/3).eval()
```